# Hypothesis test for a parameter when only the upper and lower bounds of the parameter are estimable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bounds

Consider a null hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
H_0:\;\beta=0
\end{align*}
Here, we can estimate only the upper and lower bounds of $\beta$.

To be clear, let the upper and lower bounds of $\beta$ be $\alpha_u$ and $\alpha_l$, respectively, then what we can get is the estimate $[\widehat{\alpha}_l,\widehat{\alpha}_u]$.

I am wondering whether is it possible to test the null hypothesis only using the estimates $\widehat{\alpha}_l$ and $\widehat{\alpha}_u$.

Is there a reference that deals with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\beta$ is a parameter (not a random quantity), it has some true scalar value, therefore it does not have an upper and lower bounds.

Sometimes we use confidence intervals which are random (since they are based on the random sample), which we have a level of confidence (usually denoted by $1 - \alpha$) that indeed covers the parameter.

The (parametric) CI is equivalent to an hypothesis testing at significance level $\alpha$.